# Fade image out, new image fades on top of image thumbnail gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

http://jsfiddle.net/nUBmh/2/

I ultimately want to have a thumbnail gallery - So say I click Image1 button, it will change the image. I can then transition this image to DAY or NIGHT, essentially it will be 2 images for each button. Image2 button, changes the current image and I can transition this to DAY or NIGHT - and so on for Image3 button etc.  I have this jsfiddle code for my DAY to NIGHT transition but I want to implement this for more images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var opacityOfNight = 0;
$('.turnNightBtn').click(function(){

    if (opacityOfNight == 1){
        opacityOfNight = 0;
    } else {
        opacityOfNight += 0.05;

        if(opacityOfNight > 1) {
            opacityOfNight = 1;   
        }   
    }

    $('.night_img').css({
        opacity : opacityOfNight 
    });

});


$('.turnDayBtn').click(function(){

    if (opacityOfNight == 1){
        opacityOfNight = 0;
    } else {
        opacityOfNight -= 0.05;

        if(opacityOfNight < 0) {
            opacityOfNight = 0;   
        }   
    }

    $('.night_img').css({
        opacity : opacityOfNight 
    });

});
```

});

Comment: do you mean you want that just clicking on 1 button to turn the image to night or day (with fading effect) without having to click the button multiple times?

Comment: does it *have* to use jquery, or can it be a css only solution? A non-fade click solution is in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUBmh/6/ if you want a transition animation it may be easier with just css...

Comment: The code I have now, I want to keep that effect when I continuously click on the day or night button.  What I want to do is implement this code into a thumbnail gallery setting OR switch to a new set of images by clicking a button.  Meaning - when I change the image, it will have 2 images to transition from day to night.  I hope that made sense.

Comment: So say I click Image1 button, it will change the image.  I can then transition this image to DAY or NIGHT, essentially it will be 2 images for each button.  Image2 button, changes the current image and I can transition this to DAY or NIGHT - and so on for Image3 button etc...

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the fade in/out to complete fully rather than move in steps?  If so, change your jQuery to the following and it will complete the full fade in/out without breaking it into steps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.turnNightBtn').click(function(){
        $(".night_img").fadeIn("fast",function() {
            $(".day_img").fadeOut()});

    });


    $('.turnDayBtn').click(function(){
        $(".day_img").fadeIn("fast",function() {
            $(".night_img").fadeOut()});

    });
});
```

Comment: The code I have now http://jsfiddle.net/nUBmh/2/ I want to keep how it is.  I need the continuous clicking to fade in or out.  I want to implement this with other images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Example)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var opacityOfNight = 0;
    var interval;
    $('.turnNightBtn').click(function(){        
        interval = setInterval(turnDark, 500); 
       });

    function turnDark() { 
        $('.night_img').css({
            opacity : opacityOfNight 
        })                               
        opacityOfNight += 0.05;  
        if (opacityOfNight > 1)
             clearInterval(interval);
    }


    $('.turnDayBtn').click(function(){              
        interval = setInterval(turnLight, 500);                               
    });

    function turnLight() { 
        $('.night_img').css({
            opacity : opacityOfNight 
        })                               
        opacityOfNight -= 0.05;  
        if (opacityOfNight < 0)
             clearInterval(interval);
    }

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nUBmh/14/)**

Comment: This doesn't do what I want it to.